# IncludeNamespace in XML using JavaScript/XLS Function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have the below payload in XML. I want to include a namespace for each tag. I cant  use Find and Replace for the (Find '<' and replace '

### XML Payload::-

```
<ROWSET>
            <ROW>
                <RECEIPT_METHOD_ID>-1</RECEIPT_METHOD_ID>
                <CREATED_BY>SEED_DATA_FROM_APPLICATION</CREATED_BY>
                <CREATION_DATE>2018-12-14T18:10:42.257+00:00</CREATION_DATE>
                <LAST_UPDATED_BY>abcd</LAST_UPDATED_BY>
                <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2019-10-18T09:27:51.159+00:00</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
                <NAME>ORA_AP/AR Netting</NAME>
                <RECEIPT_CLASS_ID>-1</RECEIPT_CLASS_ID>
                <START_DATE>1952-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00</START_DATE>
                <AUTO_PRINT_PROGRAM_ID/>
                <AUTO_TRANS_PROGRAM_ID/>
                <END_DATE>null</END_DATE>
```

---

**I want it in the below format::---**

```
<nstrgdfl:ROWSET>
            <nstrgdfl:ROW>
                <nstrgdfl:RECEIPT_METHOD_ID>-1</nstrgdfl:RECEIPT_METHOD_ID>
                <nstrgdfl:CREATED_BY>SEED_DATA_FROM_APPLICATION</nstrgdfl:CREATED_BY>
                <nstrgdfl:CREATION_DATE>2018-12-14T18:10:42.257+00:00</nstrgdfl:CREATION_DATE>
                <nstrgdfl:LAST_UPDATED_BY>abcd</nstrgdfl:LAST_UPDATED_BY>
                <nstrgdfl:LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2019-10-18T09:27:51.159+00:00</nstrgdfl:LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
                <nstrgdfl:NAME>ORA_AP/AR Netting</nstrgdfl:NAME>
                <nstrgdfl:RECEIPT_CLASS_ID>-1</nstrgdfl:RECEIPT_CLASS_ID>
                <nstrgdfl:START_DATE>1952-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00</nstrgdfl:START_DATE>
                <nstrgdfl:AUTO_PRINT_PROGRAM_ID/>
                <nstrgdfl:AUTO_TRANS_PROGRAM_ID/>
                <nstrgdfl:END_DATE>null</nstrgdfl:END_DATE>
```

*

**Below Is the Current XSL Mapping which is being used:: Please not that my Input XML is present in the variable $Base64DecodedData_Report( /.....)** 
XSL MApping:--

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xml:id="id_1" xmlns:nstrgdfl="http://www.example.org" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/CallCommonERPQuery_REQUEST/types" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/CallCommonERPQuery_REQUEST" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/CallCommonERPQuery" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes=" oraext xsd xp20 ora oracle-xsl-mapper xsi fn xsl ignore01" xmlns:ignore01="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" ignore01:ignorexmlids="true" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:nsmpr0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService" xmlns:nsmpr1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/types/CallReportServiceERP/OutboundSOAPRequestDocument">
   <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema xml:id="id_2">
      <!--SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY.-->
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources xml:id="id_3">
         <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL" xml:id="id_4">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/CallCommonERPQuery_REQUEST.wsdl" xml:id="id_5"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="execute" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/CallCommonERPQuery_REQUEST/types" xml:id="id_6"/>
         </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets xml:id="id_7">
         <oracle-xsl-mapper:target type="WSDL" xml:id="id_8">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../../application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/CallCommonERPQuery_REQUEST.wsdl" xml:id="id_9"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="executeResponse" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/CallCommonERPQuery_REQUEST/types" xml:id="id_10"/>
         </oracle-xsl-mapper:target>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
      <!--GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 12.1.2.0.0-->
   </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>

   <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
   <xsl:param name="Status" xml:id="id_23"/>
   <xsl:param name="Base64DecodedData_Report" xml:id="id_38"/>
   <xsl:template match="/" xml:id="id_11">
      <nstrgmpr:executeResponse xml:id="id_12">
         <nstrgdfl:Response xml:id="id_27">
            <nstrgdfl:Status xml:id="id_28">
               <xsl:value-of select="$Status" xml:id="id_29"/>
            </nstrgdfl:Status>
         <nstrgdfl:QueryOutput xml:id="id_44">
               <xsl:copy-of select="oraext:parseEscapedXML($Base64DecodedData_Report)" xml:id="id_45"/>
            </nstrgdfl:QueryOutput>
         </nstrgdfl:Response>
      </nstrgmpr:executeResponse>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The format you want is not well-formed XML: you cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:nstrgdfl="http://www.url.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node() except *">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('nstrgdfl:',name())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5E7

Comment: And where did you get `xmlns:nstrgdfl="http://www.url.com"`??

Comment: I just suggest it user can use as per their own thats why i wrote url.com

Comment: Where exactly we need to pass this xsl ??..In my mapping  Base64DecodedData_Report is the input string..and I am putting it into the XML using copy of...this is the example of that::----    <nstrgdfl:QueryOutput xml:id="id_44">
               <xsl:copy-of select="oraext:parseEscapedXML($Base64DecodedData_Report)" xml:id="id_45"/>
            </nstrgdfl:QueryOutput>
         </nstrgdfl:Response>